# Stuck On Proving A Function Is Injective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $f_1: A \implies B$ and $f_2: C \implies D$ be bijective function, where $A$ and $C$ are pairwise disjoint, and $B$ and $D$ are pairwise disjoint. Let $f = f_1\bigcup f_2$; prove that $f: A\bigcup C \implies B \bigcup D$ is a bijective function.

Now, to prove that the function is bijective is to prove that it is both injective and surjective. However, I am having trouble proving that it's injective. Here is how my proof is going (we must show that if $(x_1,y) \in f$ and $(x_2,y) \in f$ then $x_1 = x_2$.

Assume that $(x_1,y) \in f$ and $(x_2,y) \in f$. From the stated conditions it follows that $((x_1,y) \in f_1$ or $(x_1,y) \in f_2) $and $((x_2,y) \in f_1$ or$ (x_2,y) \in f_2)$. I am stuck exactly here. I was thinking that I'm supposed to somehow show that $((x_1,y) \in f_1 $ and $(x_2,y) \in f_1)$ or $((x_1,y) \in f_2 $and$ (x_2,y) \in f_2)$. Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are both bijective, it follows that in either case $x_1 = x_2$. However, how do I do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x_1,y)\in f$ and $(x_2,y)\in f$, then you can't have $x_1\in A$ and $x_2\in C$, because otherwise $y$ would belong to both sets $B$ and $D$. This is impossible, since $B$ and $D$ are disjoint. For the same reason, you can't have $x_1\in C$ and $x_2\in A$. So, either $x_1,x_2\in A$ or $x_1,x_2\in C$. But

- if $x_1,x_2\in A$, then, since $f_1$ is injective, $x_1=x_2$;
- if $x_1,x_2\in C$, then, since $f_2$ is injective, $x_1=x_2$.